# Round UIImage disappear in UITableViewCell only in Swift 3

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, swift3

Round UIImage disappear in UITableViewCell only in Swift 3, in previous version its working fine, but i am not getting any best solution for it.

Here is my code:-

```
   cell.imgView_User.layer.cornerRadius = cell.imgView_User.frame.width/2
   cell. imgView_User.layer.masksToBounds = false
   cell.imgView_User.clipsToBounds = true
   cell.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case this working fine following is my working code :

```
 let imageview = cell.viewWithTag(105) as! UIImageView
 imageview.layer.cornerRadius = imageview.frame.width/2
 imageview.clipsToBounds = true
 imageview.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
 imageview.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
```

I have a set border color for identify the our result.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `cornerRadius` manually fixed the problem for me.

For example:

```
imgView.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0;
```

Only use this if you know your image view's frame won't affected by auto layouts. i.e. a fiexed size.

Answer (score -1):

in iOS 10 , all layer operation do in "viewDidLayoutSubviews" or "viewDidAppear" method for uiviewController.

For UITableViewCell or collectionViewCell , subClass your cell and write layer operation in "drawRect" method

for your case Ex:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    self.imgView_User.layer.cornerRadius = self.imgView_User.frame.width/2
    self.imgView_User.layer.masksToBounds = false
    self.imgView_User.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

Comment: No, do not put this code in `drawRect`. `layoutSubviews` is a much better place for such code.

Comment: `drawRect` should only be used to draw the content of the view. None of this code draws the content of the view. In addition, two of those three lines only need to be called once, not over and over. And the first line should only be called when the view's frame changes. Using `drawRect` might work, but that doesn't mean it is the correct solution. Put code where it belongs, not where it just happens to work.

Comment: but how can i place cell image in viewDidLayoutSubviews?

Comment: @amit ... do layer operation of ViewController's subviews in   "viewDidLayoutSubviews" method..

For Custom Cell do in "drawRect" or "layoutSubviews" method

Comment: @rmaddy .... code is not working if i put in "layoutSubviews"  , view not visible